# Haskell fold left over infinite list not applying lazy evaluation

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, fold, foldleft

From my understanding, as Haskell uses lazy evaluation, which allows operations on for example infinite lists to be evaluated in a finite amount of time.

As a test, I defined the following function

```
X Boolean
Y Int

f(X,Y) = (Y == 3) OR X
```

Hence, fold left applied to the infinite list of integers `[1..]` with `False` as initial value and the function defined above, should return `True`, because when it will reach `n=3` evaluating `f(n==3,False)` will return `True`, and hence this `True` will propagate through the function.

I implemented this function in Haskell code

```
myfunc :: Bool -> Int -> Bool
myfunc True _ = True
myfunc _ n
  | (n == 3)  = True
  | otherwise = False
```

and tried it out in the cli

```
foldl myfunc False [1..]
```

The command becomes unresponsive, suggesting it is doing an infinite computation. Why is Haskell not benefiting from the lazy evaluation here?

Comment: `foldl` is indeed not lazy, since it folds `f (f (f z x1) x2) x3 ...`, hence it needs to reach the end of the list. That is why `foldr` is often more advisable in terms of laziness.

Comment: This looks however like a simple `any`: your last function is equivalent to `any (3 ==) [1..3]`.

Comment: I suspect part of the misunderstanding here is thinking that the l and r ind foldl and foldr mean "start at the left of the list and process towards the right" or "start at the right of the list and process towards the left". But that's not so. Instead, it stands for "associate the combining operation to the left" or "associate the combining operation to the right". In practice this frequently means foldl starts evaluating at the right end of the list and foldr starts at the left end!

Answer (score 5):

Because `foldl` always must traverse its argument list *in whole* before starting reducing it into the final result; and `foldl'` traverses the argument list *in whole* while reducing it into the final result:

```
foldl f z [x1, x2, ..., xn]  ==           foldl f (f z x1) [x2, ..., xn]

foldl' f z [x1, x2, ..., xn]  ==  z `seq` foldl' f (f z x1) [x2, ..., xn]

-- thus,

foldl f z1 [x1, x2, ..., xn]  ==  f (...(f (f z1 x1) x2)...) xn

foldl' f z1 [x1, x2, ..., xn]  ==  z1 `seq` (let z2 = f z1 x1  in
                                    z2 `seq` (let z3 = f z2 x2  in
                                     z3 `seq` (... `seq` (f zn xn)...)))
```

You though wanted to be able to stop the traversal, which is done via *right* fold with a non-strict reducing function:

```
present y xs  =  foldr myfunc False xs 
  where
  myfunc x r  =  y == x || r
```

Because `myfunc` is non-strict in its second argument, `foldr myfunc` explores the list `xs` in the *left-to-right* order,

```
foldr myfunc False (x:xs)  =  myfunc x (foldr myfunc False xs)
                           =  y == x || foldr myfunc False xs
```